# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No constructor for class com.install4j.api.context.OverwriteMode found

Tags: java

I want to set up Geneious program but I get following exception error:

```
Exception:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No constructor for class com.install4j.api.context.OverwriteMode found
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.Handler.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.SaxOutputter.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.SaxOutputter.element(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.SaxOutputter.element(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.SaxOutputter.element(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.SaxOutputter.element(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.SaxOutputter.output(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.XMLDecoder.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.xmldecode.XMLDecoder.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig.instantiateBean(Unknown Source)
```

...

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Add the code you have writtenr

Comment: [You can download full error text](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Uh_gZUe6RiRFlYdTR1ekdtSEk)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to call a constructor for [OverwriteMode](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/context/OverwriteMode.html)?

you should the enum constants: `OverwriteMode.ALWAYS`, `OverwriteMode.NEVER`, ... (found them all on linked page)